# Visual Studio compile error in Windows 7 when required interface is defined only in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, compilation

I have a project (C#) which has a reference to **Interop.NetFwTypeLib**. Somewhere in my code I have this cast:

```
var netFwRule3 = rule as INetFwRule3;
if (netFwRule3 != null)
{
   // set some properties
}
```

The problem is that **INetFwRule3** exists only in Windows 10. I am currently on Windows 7 and this interface does not exist.

To be able to compile my solution I have created a dummy interface with the same name and added into it the definitions of the properties that I need. If I compile this on Windows 7, it will work as INetFwRule3 will be never used, but on Windows 10 it will use my dummy interface not the real one. If I compile it on Windows 10 then it works in Windows 7 too, even if the interface does not exist in Windows 7 because the cast will result in a null value.

How to deal with this kind of scenarios ? Do I have to use always Windows 10 to compile my software ?

Thank you.

**LATER EDIT**

I have found a solution. In Windows 10 the assembly **Interop.NetFwTypeLib.dll** is different than in Windows 7. It is created when compiling the solution in the **obj\x86** folder of the project. I have copied this dll from a Windows 10 machine and created a Dependencies subfolder in my solution where I copied it. Instead of referencing the COM object, I add a reference into my project to this local file. The result is that I have the **INetFwRule3** in Windows 7 and I can compile my solution without problems.

Comment: Maybe this post will be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112051/c-compile-time-macros-to-detect-windows-os

Comment: Unfortunately, this applies only for C++ while my solution is in C#.

Comment: See my later edit on how I resolved this problem. The answer from the other "duplicated" question did not solve my problem.