# Define for Os version in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem, I cannot find a way to detect windows version at compilation time.

My purpose is to create an executable that depend on Interface, which are defined only in specific version of windows.

So to make my executable cross windows version I want to be able to define include and part of code for specific windows version.

First, is it possible to have include for specific windows version at compilation time?

Second, if not, what is the best way to design an application for multi windows OS version? One executable per version?

Thanks a lot for your time,

Comment: Maybe we can turn around the question: what calls are OS specific? Maybe there is a way to work them out.

Comment: Why do you want to determine this at compile time? Can't you include code for all versions and determine which code to call at runtime?

Comment: For example If I want to be able to work with INetFwRule, that INetFwRule3 is defined only in windows 10. I want to write my code in one application(.exe) for each OS

Comment: The OS at compilation time is the OS of your build machine. I suspect you really want to ask how to create portable libraries? Or how to create *separate* binaries per OS, as defined by *you*?

Comment: Use Environment.OSVersion.  It is not going to tell you that it runs on Win10,  not actually a problem since INetFwRule3 is a Win8 interface.  You can always use the `as` keyword to obtain a later interface, it will produce `null` if the interface is not supported.

Comment: Can you give example or link, how t use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really turn this around. It is better to solve this at runtime. What you can do:

- Create an interface that defines the actions you want to perform;
- Create separate implementations for different platforms (in your sample there would be a `Windows10Implementation` class, which calls `INetFwRule3`);
- Then, in your code, check for `Environment.OSVersion` and create the implementation class for that specific platform.

If necessary, you can split off the implementations in separate class libraries, so you don't always have to load OS specific stuff, but only when you need it.

Comment: Ok, so I will have to create multiple .class, with interface specific? Otherwise Visual will not compile with: include INetFwRule3 in windows 7. Because Environment.OSVersion is at running time.

Comment: Yes, you have to make separate class libraries then.

Comment: Ok, but the library that contains the code for Windows 10 still can't be compiled on Windows 7 since the INetFwRule3 does not exist in Windows 7. I still don't understand how to do this. I have a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454774/visual-studio-compile-error-in-windows-7-when-required-interface-is-defined-only

Comment: Of course you can. External calls (to win32) are bound on runtime. So you copy the definition of the external method and the structs and compile your code. On runtime .net will bind the method to the right library version.

Comment: Just for you to know, I upvoted instead of downvote, and offers you the answer. I think there was a misunderstanding.

Comment: I know you did @destrif. Somebody else did.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to trigger compilation of some source code from the running application? I could imagine this is possible. In that case, you should be able to find OS version in **Environment.OSVersion**

But better approach would be :

> .. include code for all versions and determine which code to call at runtime ..

as proposed by CodeCaster in comments.