# compile time windows version wishful thinking

Tags: c++, windows, c++17

To show exactly what I would like to have, basically I have taken the code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/getting-the-system-version) , and transformed it into wishful thinking as bellow:

```
int wmain( int argc, PCWSTR argv[] )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argc);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argv);

    if constexpr (IsWindowsXPOrGreater())
    {
        printf("XPOrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindowsXPSP1OrGreater())
    {
        printf("XPSP1OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindowsXPSP2OrGreater())
    {
        printf("XPSP2OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindowsXPSP3OrGreater())
    {
        printf("XPSP3OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())
    {
        printf("VistaOrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindowsVistaSP1OrGreater())
    {
        printf("VistaSP1OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindowsVistaSP2OrGreater())
    {
        printf("VistaSP2OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindows7OrGreater())
    {
        printf("Windows7OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindows7SP1OrGreater())
    {
        printf("Windows7SP1OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindows8OrGreater())
    {
        printf("Windows8OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindows8Point1OrGreater())
    {
        printf("Windows8Point1OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindows10OrGreater())
    {
        printf("Windows10OrGreater\n");
    }
    else if constexpr (IsWindowsServer())
    {
        printf("Server\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Client\n");
    }
}
```

The aim is obviously to have standard C++ code, using `constexpr-if` with windows version compile time detection. It is all there in `VersionHelpers.h` but it is not compile time C++17.

Functions from `VersionHelpers.h`, are not returning constexpr values. The question is if anyone has done such a thing? Or a different implementation to achieve the same?

Comment: So, do you want to detect if the computer you're building on is a certain version or the computer you're running on? Because the latter is impossible to do compile time.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112051/c-compile-time-macros-to-detect-windows-os  You can use the provided information in the link to write your own version of this.

Comment: `constexpr-if` requires compile time value, yet this "Sombrero Chicken" who obviously has misunderstood this C++ feature, gets +2 nevertheless? And I get -2 (so far), I assume from some other chicken ...

Comment: The simplest and generally lowest-effort method is to restrict yourself to API facilities that are present in the oldest OS version that you plan to support.  This does not, in my experience, significantly limit your capabilities except in certain edge cases like complex console UIs. Microsoft's documentation is quite useful for this, as it clearly indicates the minimum supported version(s).

Answer (score 2):

This is fundamentally impossible.

Although library/OS versions sometimes impose practical constraints on deployment, compilers generally target *architectures*, not operating systems

If you build your code on computer A, how can the compiler know the OS of computer B where the compiled program will be run?.

So that's one reason that none of it is `constexpr`.

[Here's an exploration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10112150/560648) of some more runtime avenues.

Comment: thanks but ...  `constexpr-if` requires compile time values. Compilation happens on computer A, I do care for only computer A, not B.. Just like `__FILE__` gets replaced before compile time with the file name aka compilation unit, I see no fundamental reason why can't we have (for example) `__OS__` predefined macro. This is fundamentally possible. Just if compiler would be able to provide it. Like any other predefined macro, that is.

Comment: @Chef Right, which is why you can't use `if constexpr` for this data. On to choosing some compile-time data, what is the value of determining which OS the _build_ system uses? That is not the conventional model. Again, perhaps you have chosen that you will only deploy to the same computer that builds the program, but C++ doesn't know that and neither does Microsoft. You could try passing in this information from your build system via macros - probably your only shot.

Comment: exactly. I could write a script or ide macro, to introduce the OS version number before compilation starts. It will be only for Windows and it will use the 'OS' `envvar` to generate one of the "standard" constants as defined by MS for Win version numbering. I see no fundamental obstacles to that. Thanks again for the discussion.

Comment: @ChefGladiator Trouble is as soon as you move that .exe to another computer, depending on what you're doing with that information the results could be just about anything. This is really not considered to be a good idea.

Comment: @Lighness, I am perfectly aware of it. The "best" solution is to read a config at run-time, which config is automatically morphing in accordance with the platform. And that is env var's. But this particular use case is for WIN7 to stay on WIN7 "for ever".  So kernel32.dll and friends are a true legacy over there, while we are developing on WIN10, and trying not to over engineer anything. 

Customer is always right ...

Comment: @ChefGladiator Or make it portable so that it doesn't matter and then the customer is always right and your software is always right too. I don't think I've ever seen software where you have to download different versions for Win7 and Win10 and there's a good reason for that.

Comment: System needs a function from KERNEL32.DLL in its WIN7 form, because they have decided to stay on WIN7 as long as possible, and beyond. So exe is staying on W7 and yes it will work on "any" W7 machine. We could indeed do the run-time no-macros checks and there is an official header for that: `versionhelpers.h` . Which I have to test as there is/was something "funny" with that ... have not head time to test...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185892/discussion-between-chef-gladiator-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).